# Is there a default cert that can be used for SSL with localhost without installation?

Tags: ssl, certificate, https, asp.net

I have an app that will require a simple webserver to run (https) on localhost. I need to install this server on many devices. I can create a server certificate, but I want to avoid manually installing a client certificate on every device.

Is there a default server certificate available that I can use on localhost?

Comment: Hi Mars, you can use any certificate where you have the private key, provided you don't care about errors.  Do you have one?

Comment: @Paul Yeah, I'm the one that generated and signed the certificate. I care about errors though

Comment: @Paul I updated the question and gave a temporary answer, if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect answer to the question, but as I have been unable to find a server cert that works without the installation of a client cert, my approach is to script the installation.

For windows, as Admin:

```
rem Addcert.bat

certutil -addstore "Root" "MyCertFile.crt"
```